# Google Analytics - View filters and API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have defined some filters on an analytics view (via googles website). When you are connecting to GA via the API, you must specify a view id, so I expect the filters to work and be applied to the data requested via the API. But that's not the case. I know you can build custom filters in the API request, but why, if it's already defined in the view.
Any idea?

Comment: Filters applied to the view in the view settings are working via the API, that's the whole point. If you experience something different you are either doing something wrong or there is a bug (however for me this works just fine; still, bugs do happen). Filters defined via the UI will not work via the API. Segments will work, but need to be specified in your query.

Comment: What is the difference between "in the view" and "via the UI". For me, they are both the same. I defined filters via de google analytics UI in a particular view.

Comment: That was perhaps unfortunately phrased. Filters set in the admin section/view settings work. Everything you set in the reporting interface does not work or (in the case of segments) needs to be specified explicitly.